# Telerik Scheduler

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik-scheduler

Does anyone know how get rid of this error message "Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection. Parameter name: index mscorlib"?

Project is Using the Telerik Scheduler File Version 2017.1.228.45 after deployed.

Project created with Visual Studio 2019 as Web Form (Not Core or MVC Project) using the Framework 4.7 and deployed on the Windows 2019 - IIS 10.

The Telerik Scheduler works 100% within the Visual Studio IDE the error is only thrown after is the Web Form project is deployed at the Hosting Service. The Error only occurs when trying to navigate [Day, Week, Month and TimeLine]

Thanks
Jose